# how to prove the well-ordering principle using the principle of complete mathematical induction

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction, well-orders

i know what both principles are saying but I don't get how they could connect with each other, could anyone give an detailed proof please? thank you so much!

Comment: Prove by induction that a set which has no least element must be empty. If a set has no  least element, then $0$ isn't in it. And if no elements $<k$ are in it, can $k$ be in it?

Comment: (The proof-verification tag is for questions where you provide a proof and want verification and suggestions for improvements.)

Comment: The idea is to use strong induction on $n$ to prove: for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, for all $S \subseteq \mathbb{N}$, if $n \in S$ then $S$ has a smallest element.

Comment: This question has been asked many times before. Please look under 'Related' on the right to find some older posts and Answers.